# listview scrolling changes background color of item views (simpleadapter)

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I have a problem with listview and `simpleadapter`. I change the background color of views of some rows when first-time `listview` simpleadapter get binded. the problem is when I scroll listview it changes the background color of views randomly. I really don't understand what's happening here. I use a variable(coloringDone) to check if listview binded already so avoid changing color again(in simpleadapter `getView` method) and I set this variable to true in `onLayoutChange` method when first-time `listview` loaded. I put a breakpoint in `getView` method after `coloringDone` if and it doesn't hit.

my lisview item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
        android:id="@+id/person_spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Receiver_Name"
        android:layout_width="190dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textAlignment="gravity" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Asset_Name"
        android:layout_width="190dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textAlignment="gravity" />


</LinearLayout>
```

my simpleadapter:

```
public class AssetSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
public AssetSimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, String>> data,
                          int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    mContext = context;
}

Context mContext;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);



    if (!((MainActivity) mainActivity).coloringDone && some other conditions) {


            ((TextView) ((LinearLayout) view).findViewById(R.id.Asset_Name)).setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            ((TextView) ((LinearLayout) view).findViewById(R.id.Receiver_Name)).setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));




    }


    return view;

}
```

}

and MainActivity:

```
public boolean coloringDone = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainActivity = this;

  ...

 tagListVU.setAdapter(adapter);
    tagListVU.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
    tagListVU.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            tagListVU.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);


               coloringDone = true;

        }
    });
```

Edit: by changing color randomly I mean some rows become red and some rows becomes white

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem. I changed the adapter to ArrayAdapter but still same problem so problem wasn't from adapter type. Problem solved by putting else clause and change the background color of views to white in getView method of adapter(and no need coloringDone variable):

```
   if (some other conditions) {

    ((TextView) ((LinearLayout) view).findViewById(R.id.Asset_Name)).setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    ((TextView) ((LinearLayout) view).findViewById(R.id.Receiver_Name)).setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

}
else{

    ((TextView) ((LinearLayout) view).findViewById(R.id.Asset_Name)).setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    ((TextView) ((LinearLayout) view).findViewById(R.id.Receiver_Name)).setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

}
```